# How to access controls inside a parent control in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a class `Player`, if I have a List of Players and I want for each `Player` in this list to have a card that is basically a `Grid` that contains an `Image` and a `TextBlock`, how do I do that?

The card is a style for a `ListViewItem`.

Here is the class:

```
    public class Player
    {
        public string firstname;
        public string lastname;
        public string position;
        public int points;
        public int price;
        public Club club;
    }
```

And here is the style:

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="PlayerCard">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">

            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,0.5"
                            BorderBrush="#999999"
                            Height="50"
                            Width="280"
                            Margin="8,5">

                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Border Grid.Column="0"
                                    BorderBrush="#05F1FF"
                                    BorderThickness="1"
                                    CornerRadius="1"
                                    ClipToBounds="True">

                                <Image Width="40" Stretch="Uniform"/>

                            </Border>

                            <TextBlock Margin="10"
                                       Height="30"
                                       Grid.Column="1"/>
                            
                        </Grid>

                    </Border>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
            
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Also I am new to XAML and Wpf in general

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for Data Templates and Item Templates. Have a read of this: https://wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/

Comment: See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). Make sure the elements in the Player class are public properties, not fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `ItemTemplate`:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,0.5"
                            BorderBrush="#999999"
                            Height="50"
                            Width="280"
                            Margin="8,5">

                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Border Grid.Column="0"
                                    BorderBrush="#05F1FF"
                                    BorderThickness="1"
                                    CornerRadius="1"
                                    ClipToBounds="True">

                        <Image Width="40" Stretch="Uniform"/>

                    </Border>

                    <TextBlock Margin="10"
                                       Height="30"
                                       Grid.Column="1"
                                       Text="{Binding Lastname}"/>

                </Grid>

            </Border>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Note that for you to be able to bind an element in the template to your `Player` class, you must define the members of the `Player` class as public *properties*, e.g.:

```
public class Player
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public int Points { get; set; } 
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public Club Club { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, don't forget to set or bind the `ItemsSource` property to your `List<Player>`:

```
List<Player> players = ...;
listView.ItemsSource = players;
```